# How to correctly retrieve a document from PropDB using specific formatting in the http Trigger GET request (Azure Function)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Here is my issue:

I am trying to set-up an http trigger using Azure functions in javascript. I have been able to post this data into Cosmosdb using my POST function.
CosmosDB Example Item I am looking for:

```
{
    "id": "POLL:FAVECOLORS:LM:LMBWZ18",
    "partition": "POLL:LM",
    "value": {
        "name": "fave colors poll",
        "question": "Which color do you like the most?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "text": "Orange",
                "count": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Yellow",
                "count": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Blue",
                "count": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "_rid": "<info>",
    "_self": "<info>",
    "_etag": "\"<info>\"",
    "_attachments": "<info>/",
    "_ts": <info>
}
```

I am trying to pull this information via input into my Azure Function.
Here is my function.json.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "<MyURL>/{type}/{objname}/{brand}/{site}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post",
        "patch"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "CosmosSend",
      "type": "documentDB",
      "databaseName": "PropDB",
      "collectionName": "WithoutCCN",
      "createIfNotExists": false,
      "connection": "<Connection-Info>",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "documents",
      "databaseName": "PropDB",
      "collectionName": "WithoutCCN",
      "connection": "<Connection-Info>",
      "direction": "in",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = {id}"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

I am not sure how I can change my requests format so that it uses the request parameters for the query instead of looking for "https:///{type}/{objname}/{brand}/{site}?id=POLL:FAVECOLORS:LM:LMBWZ18"

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var documents = context.bindings.documents;
    var totalDocuments = documents.length;
    var azureAppId = req.headers["azure-app-id"];
    context.log('azure-app-id = ' + azureAppId);
     var idx = '' + (req.params.type + ':' + req.params.objname + ':' + req.params.brand + ':' + req.params.site).toUpperCase();
      var paritionx = '' + (req.params.type + ":" + req.params.brand).toUpperCase();
       var valuex = req.body;


    if (req.method === 'GET') {
            context.log('Found '+ totalDocuments +' documents');

            if(totalDocuments === 0)
{
                context.done(null, createResult(200, 'application/json', "The 
                requested document was not found."));

    }
    else {
        context.done(null, createResult(200, 'application/json', documents));
    }


    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
        if (typeof req.body === 'object') {

            context.bindings.CosmosSend = JSON.stringify({
            id: idx,
            partition: paritionx,
            value: valuex
            });

            context.done(null, createResult(201, 'application/json', req.body));
        }
        else {
            context.done(null, createResult(400, 'text/plain', 'The message must be of type application/json.'));
        }
```

I have tried to take the variable 'idx' and put that into the query since it is already in the same format as the POST sends the 'id', but since it is not apart of the function.json itself it cannot be found. If I change the query in the function to:

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = /"{TYPE}:{OBJNAME}:{BRAND}:{SITE}/""
```

and anything remotely close to that kinda thinking it doesnt work. If I shove what I am looking for exactly into it:

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = \"POLL:FAVECOLORS:LM:LMBWZ18\""
```

It will find it perfectly every time, but only that one record, and it defeats the purpose of the GET request including its own target information. 
I have really been racking my brain on this issue and any tips would really help. I have read a lot of microsoft docs related to the Azure Function and javascript but nothing has helped with this specific issue.

The expected results will be the item in cosmos returned when given the http GET request from the Azure Function app. it will look for the item by the information located in the URL of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `id` as an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint) in the route?

```
"route": "<MyURL>/{type:alpha}/{objname:alpha}/{brand:alpha}/{site:alpha}/{id:alpha?}",
```

Keep in mind though, that doing this in the same HTTP Trigger Function will always execute the query, even on a POST where you don't send the id. So you are consuming RU's that you are not using.

Ideally you would split this into separate Functions, one for POST, one for GET, which helps them scale independently and you have a greater separation of concerns.

Comment: The reason I have not added the Id in the route was because it is made from the 4 route parameters combined, and adding 'id' to the route would mean changing how the websites interact with the function app when sending requests to include the new parameter. If I were to separate the Get and Post into separate Azure functions, could I still pass data to one another directly?

Comment: What do you mean by pass data? Your Function does 2 different things on GET and POST, so you could have one function do what is in `if (req.method === 'GET') {` and another function do what happens in `else if (req.method === 'POST') {`, with different routes (the one for GET with the `{id}`).